# can't boot from usb on windows 10, no enable csm option

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, lubuntu

I'm trying to install linux oprating system on my laptop with windows 10.
When I'm trying to boot I don't have the "enable csm" option, I tried to do - UEFI reset, disable secure boot control and restarting.
Nothing helped I still have on my bios boot screen only fast boot option...
How can I still delete windows 10 and install linux os?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Linux distro with UEFI support. Ubuntu and Fedora are known to support UEFI (+Secure Boot). You also need to ensure you properly write iso file onto USB flash drive, either write it byte-by-byte (with dd or graphical counterparts like [Rosa ImageWriter](http://wiki.rosalab.ru/en/index.php/ROSA_ImageWriter) or [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/)), or you need to create FAT32 partition and copy all files from iso to it.